# Cannot subscript a value of [AnyObject]? with an index of type String

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

In the function below, I am trying to find the current user in the `Users` table on Parse.com by the username and add/update a field value called `salaryMode`.

Below is my function and the error I am getting:

*Error I see*:
[image]

> Cannot subscript a value of [AnyObject]? with an index of type String

```
func saveUserSalaryInfo() {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (users: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {

            users["salaryMode"] = self.salaryMode

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            //NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `users` is declared as an array but you try to use it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no, you cannot access an array using a subscript of type String

Long answer:

`users: [AnyObject]?` This means that the user variable holds an optional type. So it can be nil, or if anything, an Array of AnyObject (which allows for anything really). But this is an array: so index-based access needs numbers.

You're confusing this for a Dictionary, which has a similar syntax to access elements using a key

```swift
// Array

let array: [String] = ["one", "two", "three"]

array[0] // "one"

array["one"]   // error

// Dictionary

let brothers = ["one": "Groucho", "two": "Chico", "three": "Harpo"]

brothers["one"] // Groucho
```